# Filtering a IQueryable with results from another table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an EF query which gets products from the database.

```
var query = (from pPrice in db.ProductPricing
             join prod in db.Products on pPrice.ProductID equals prod.ProductID
             join productExt in db.ProductsExt on prod.ProductID equals productExt.ProductID into pExts
             from prodExt in pExts.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where (includeNonPublic || pPrice.ShowOnline == 1)
                 && ((eventID.HasValue && pPrice.EventID == eventID) || (!eventID.HasValue && !pPrice.EventID.HasValue))
             orderby prod.DisplayOrder
             select new ProductPricingInfo()
             {
                 Product = prod,
                 ProductPricing = pPrice,
                 ProductExtension = prodExt
             });
```

I have a table where I can specify add-on products (products which can be bought once the parent item has been bought).

My query to fetch these add-on products is

```
var addOnProductsQuery = (from pa in db.ProductAddons
                         where pa.EventID == eventID && pa.StatusID == 1
                         select new { ProductID = pa.ChildProductId });
```

Now what I am trying to do is filter on the query variable to only return products which are not in the addOnProductsQuery result.

Currently I have

```
var addOnProducts = addOnProductsQuery.ToList();
query = query.Where(e => !addOnProducts.Contains(e.Product.ProductID));
```

But there is a syntax error on the Contains(e.Product.ProductID)) statement

- Argument 1: cannot convert from int to anonymous type: int ProductID

Comment: `addOnProducts` contains dynamic objects with int property. So you can not apply `Contains` operation on it to find int value. You need to change selection in addOnProductsQuery to `select pa.ChildProductId`

Answer (score 0):

Chetan is right in the comments, you need to select the integer from the object before using `Contains`.

You can do it in 2 ways:

First you could just take the integer initially:

```
var addOnProductsQuery = (from pa in db.ProductAddons
                     where pa.EventID == eventID && pa.StatusID == 1
                     select new pa.ChildProductId);
```

This should give `int` as type so you can use `Contains` later with no problem.

Second, if you want to keep the addOnProductsQuery unchanged:

```
var addOnProducts = addOnProductsQuery.Select(a => a.ProductID).ToList();
query = query.Where(e => !addOnProducts.Contains(e.Product.ProductID));
```